# Way to show download file for specific user after login

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, modx

I want user to redirect to download page after login where user can download admin-pre-uploaded file.

I want to show a pdf file for download when a user login.
Like user 1 login and redirects to his download or dashboard page where a simple download link for a file.pdf is waiting for him to be clicked.
Same with other users like user2 3 and so on.. Different file.
My client want to give his users ability to download pdf of their marriage album.
So he want like when customers login, it goes to a page where they can download their album.
How to set custom download url for each user when he login?

**Any CMS or Wordpress or PHP script is prefer.**

I tried https://userspice.com/ but failed.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Ok Now you must creat a database and tables:

1 **Table of Users**
Were the user password and user_name will be stocked or is stocked

2. **Table of file**
Were your file(pdf) will be stocked or is stocked

You will need 4 files after creat your data_base and tables
**download.php, form.php, connexion.php and get_file.php**
**Download.php** will contents this:

```
<?php session_start ();?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Download</title>
</head>

<body> 

<?php 
    if(isset($_Post['user_name']) AND isset($_Post['password'])){
        //connexion to the data_base. I use PDO
        require'connexion.php';
//end of connexion to data_base

$c =$base->query("SELECT user, password FROM registred_user_tabe WHERE user='".strip_tags($_Post['user_name'])."' AND  user='".strip_tags($_Post['password'])."'");
$usertest =$c->fetch();

    if(!empty($usertest['user']) AND $usertest['user']==$_Post['user_name']){

        //NOW you creat the session login
    $_session['connected']['user_name']=$_Post['user_name'];
    $_session['connected']['password']=$_Post['password'];
    //Now redirect user to download page or show the link
    header('location: download.php');
    }



    }
    ;?>
<?php if(isset($_session['connected'])){
    //Require get_file.php IF SESSION USER EXIST...
    require'get_file.php'
    ;}else{
    //REQUIRE form.php IF WANT CONNEXION TO DOWNLOAD FILE...
        require'form.php'
    ;};?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form.php** will contents this:

```
<h1>Connexion requirer</h1><form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="connect" target="_parent">
<label for="password"></label><input name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" placeholder="Your User Name" /><br/>
<label for="password"></label><input name="password" type="password" id="password"  placeholder="Enter Password"/><br/><input name="send" type="submit" value="SEND" id="send" /></form>
```

**Connexion.php** will contents this:

```
<?php $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_data_base', 'the_user', 'Your_password', $pdo_options);
//end of connexion to data_base;?>
```

And **get_file.php** will contents:

```
<?php 
//CONNEXION TO DATA BASE
require'connexion.php';
//LISTING ALL FILE OF USER TO DOWNLOAD
$file=$base->query("SELECT name_of_file FROM tabe_were_you_stock_file WHERE owner='".$_session['connected']['user_name']."'");
while($file_stocked =$file->fetch()){
 echo '<a href="get_file.php?id_of_file='.$file_stocked['name_of_file'].'">Download: '.$file_stocked['name_of_file'].'</a>';
;}
//END OF LISTING
//PHP IS WAITING FOR "id_of_file" TO DOWNLOAD IT
if(isset($_GET['id_of_file'])){
$that_file=htmlspecialchars($_GET['id_of_file']);

 $file = 'upload_dir/'.$that_file;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}else{echo'<strong>Error:</strong> file not found...';}}

;?>
```

Don't worry, the link of your folders will not be display with this method, it very safe.

**Pay attention: You must creat with **phpmyadmin** the data_base(if you dont have it) and the tables you'll needs!**

Comment: Hello man. All set up. But tell me how to create users and how to upload file for them ? Please check https://userspice.com/ I am sure you can modify that for me .. :) Thanks man ,, thank again.

Comment: Tel me briefly, what do you want exactly!!!!!!!!!! do you want be in your projet??? or what???

Comment: I want a cms in which admin can make users from back end to give them a page for each user when thy login.. So when user login to cms, they redirects to the page where they see a download link of a file.. And ij admin dashboard, admin can see total users and time of created.. I will draw a picture of my imagination..

Comment: no. Now I want a Client Area kind of thing where when client login, they redirects to their private page where they can see private gallery. for each client. Searching for solution in Wordpress and Joomla too. :(

Comment: Yes sure. This kind of thing is used by Medical professionals to send xray and mri files to other place for examination purpose. Different files for different doctors. Its just an example i am giving to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

first you must use session for your projet.
Just one question: **do you want user know the folder of download or not?**

First make a form submit where user can login, after handle the password and username in php like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_Post['user_name']) AND isset($_Post['password'])){
session_start ();
/*Now you make a SQL query to know if the user_name and passwor exist and they equal*/

if(sql_query_is_Ok){//NOW you creat the session login
$_session['connected']['user_name']=$_Post['user_name'];
$_session['connected']['password']=$_Post['password'];
//Now redirect user to download page
heade('location: url_where_file_can_bedownloade.php');
}



}
;>
```

In the **url_where_file_can_bedownloade.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_session['connected']['user_name']) AND isset($_session['connected']['password'])){

}else{exit('restricted area!!!');}

;?>
```

//The reste of the page will display the link to the file

```
<a href="folder/Name_of_your_file.pdf">Download: Name_of_your_file.pdf</a>
```

Comment: If you want, i can make all script for you if you dont know make a sql query!!

Comment: Yes im very new in sql query. Please make if you can :) Thanks Sir.

Comment: I dont want users to know the download folder.. I want to show them pdf download link.. And if possible, pdf view above download link.. Just like pdf book album plugin of wordpress..